# How to push elements after absolute element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to display all of an element's children after itself. I have a `<div>` wrapped in a `<section>` that has `position: absolute` and its `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` are all 0. After that `<div>`, I have another `<div>` wrapped in a `<section>`. That div just has a `<h3>` with a `<p>` under it.

This is the HTML code:

```
<main>
  <section class="fullscreen">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

...and this is the CSS:

```
main {
  clear: both;
}
main section:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -10;
}
main section:nth-child(1) div.container {
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

How can I display the page like this, without defining a margin after the `.fullscreen`?

Comment: Do you mean how do you keep the elements from moving up due to the absolutely positioned element? I think the problem is you don't like what that positioning is doing. I don't understand why you are using it at all.

Comment: What are you trying to position, where?

Comment: Can you please add demo for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it appears that you want the `section` elements to take up the full screen height.

You don't need positioning to do that. [**Viewport units**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) now have excellent support and you can just allocate the height to be 100vh.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main {
  clear: both;
  /* not required there are no floats */
}
main section {
  height: 100vh;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
main section div.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="fullscreen">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <a href="#section2">Link</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="section2">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </section>
</main>
```